# Destroy socket before or after removing it from array

Tags: node.js, sockets

In my `node.js` application I have a collection of client sockets as an array. When a communication error occurs, I simply call [`destroy`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_destroy_exception) on the socket.

My question is: should I destroy the socket before or after removing it from the array? The documentation doesn't say much.

```
var clientSockets = []

var destroySocketBefore = function(socket) {
    socket.destroy()

    var socketIdx = clientSockets.indexOf(socket)

    if (socketIdx > -1) {
        clientSockets.splice(socketIdx, 1)
    }
}    

var destroySocketAfter = function(socket) {        
    var socketIdx = clientSockets.indexOf(socket)

    if (socketIdx > -1) {
        clientSockets.splice(socketIdx, 1)
    }

    socket.destroy()
}
```

1. In the case of `destroySocketBefore`, I am not sure if the socket will be found in the array if I destroy it before searching for it, so there is a possibility that array still incorporates invalid sockets in subsequent logic.
2. In the case of `destroySocketAfter`, I am not sure if calling `destroy` on a socket that was removed from array will have the desired result. Is there a possibility that the system will delete the socket object after splicing the array, so sometimes I get to call `destroy`on a `null` object.

I tested and it seems that both methods work as there is no difference between them, so I am not sure which method is the correct one.

Comment: There is no functional difference between the two.  The array is not affected by calling `socket.destroy()` and the socket is not affected by removing it from the array so you can do them in either order.

Comment: I am not sure if `destroy`ing the socket will result in a null object, so everything will blow up.

Comment: Calling `socket.destroy()` changes state internal to the socket object, but does not make the object disappear.  It is just a method on the object.  Javascript does not have the ability to manually "free" an object the way you're thinking like you would do in C/C++.  So, the `socket` object is still there and still a Javascript object after calling `.destroy()`.  It does not matter which order you do your two operations in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either solution is valid and the two are effectively the same. The destroyed socket will get removed no matter what since there are no race conditions or anything like that (since javascript execution in node all happens on the same thread).

Answer (score 0):

splice will only remove the socket from an user defined array and will have no effect to it been closed, therefore the second method is the best option according to your answers.